# DIY OBD II "Memory saver"

Tags: battery, obd-ii

Since I had a need for a "memory saver" while changing a battery on a 05' S500 I decided that instead of borrowing one from a friend all the time, I will make my own..
Now isn't it just a power supply that giving negative 12V to pin4,5 and positive 12V to pin 16 in the OBD II port?, why do people pay for it 39.99$?

Comment: would a 'radio memory saver' work?  Basically a 9v battery to the lighter?  Guess it would depend on how your lighter is wired.

Comment: probably because they come with a rechargeable battery and an obd2 connector.

Comment: @rpmerf No, at least in Mercedes, the ECU needs to stay powered and the input is from the OBD II connector?

Comment: @Ben the expensive ones are just linear adapter..

Comment: If you don't want to pay for a "memory saver", a small battery "jump start pack" connected during the battery swap will serve the same purpose.

Comment: While your improvised solution may accomplish the task, it could also be harmful to your cars computer.  If you cross your contacts or mix them up, or short between the wrong contacts it may be possible to damage or destroy sensitive circuits and electronics.  So if it is necessary to preserve the power for the computer, I would get the right tool for the job

Answer (score 1):

So I think the easiest thing to do would be to get a 9 volt battery connector like this:

[image]

and some alligator clips with wires:

[image]

and just plug in the battery, connect the clips to the 9v connector wires and to the ends of the car's battery connectors then disconnect the the car battery and install the new one.  You could probably get it all for a few dollars at the most including the 9v battery.  Now I just thought of this while reading your question, so I've never tried it, but it seems like it should work.

[Here's an example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GKD5Q0) of a commercial 9 volt battery powered memory saver.

I saw some people who recommend putting a diode in the positive wire so there's no chance for current to flow backwards into the memory saver.

Here's a [video how to build something similar](https://youtu.be/Y5rwnMuZVbk), including the diode and explanation.

Comment: This seems extremely dangerous as when you connect this (with the 12V battery still connected as well) the 12V of the car battery will overcharge and probably set aflame the little 9V battery.

Comment: @AndréBorie How is this different than the 9v memory savers they sell which plug into the cigarette lighter?

Comment: Those ones have a diode in the path to prevent any current flowing backwards to the 9V battery. There may be more components I don't know about, and again, unless you're an electrical engineer I wouldn't recommend trying this - too much risk of screwing up (by using the wrong diode for example) and having your 9V battery burst into flames (that's not really a pleasant surprise and even less when it risks setting your entire car on fire).

Comment: @AndréBorie You are right that it shouldn't be done without putting a diode in the line to block current from flowing from the car battery to the backup battery.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use a fully charged 12V battery as a donor backup with insulating tape to insulate & secure the jump-lead clips, the positive red lead connected first & the negative black lead to chassis the same as for jump starting, battery + to + & - to -.
The 12V failing car battery voltage is likely to be lower or equal to the fully charged 12V donor-backup battery, no reverse current & no diode required.
With a 9V backup battery being lower voltage than the 12V car battery it is possible for a reverse current to flow back to charge the 9V battery, a suitable current rated diode can be inserted in the positive lead connected the right way round to prevent the possibility of this happening.
Also if you do use a small 9V battery remember that everything must be off ignition lights etc as you may only have a max of 10 minutes to change the battery before the 9V battery is drained.
This is why it is better to use a good fully charged 12V car battery.